# how to switch between maven and maven30?

Tags: homebrew

I'm working on two projects that are very specific over which maven version is required.

To this end, I have installed maven 3.0.x and maven 3.2.x on my machine using:

```
# install maven 3.2.x
brew install maven

# install maven 3.0.x
brew install homebrew/versions/maven30
```

The maven executable points to 3.2.x:

```
snowch$ which mvn
/usr/local/bin/mvn
snowch$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/mvn
lrwxr-xr-x  1 snowch  admin  29 12 Dec 08:58 /usr/local/bin/mvn -> ../Cellar/maven/3.2.3/bin/mvn
```

When I need to switch versions, I can do this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/mvn ../Cellar/maven/$requiredversion/bin/mvn
```

However, I'm hoping that there is a brew way of doing this.

**Question**: what is the brew way of switching maven versions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To switch from maven 3.2.x to 3.0.x:

```
brew unlink maven && brew link maven30
```

To switch from maven 3.0.x to 3.2.x:

```
brew unlink maven30 && brew link maven
```